# Which permissions do android live wallpapers require and how can i make my own live wallpaper app require them upon installation?

Tags: android, opengl-es, permissions, live, wallpaper

Which permissions if any do all live wallpapers require? I'm talking about the list of permissions that pops up every time you download an app. Currently my own live wallpaper requires no permissions. Please give examples or links, thanks.

BTW, all my wallpaper does is run opengl-es in the background and also has a settings screen and that's about all it uses. No network or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html